# can we remove or hide standard field from page layout "Mailing State/Province" on contact

Tags: fields

I am trying to remove this standard field "Mailing State/Province" on contact page layout but unable to remove or hide any trick to hide this field

Comment: if you want to do it dynamically then this is not possible on standard page. else create separate page layout and assign to different record type. Based on your criteria update the record type.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible because Mailing State/Province is a part of Mailing Address. You can't hide it from the contact page layout.

Comment: i know man, if any possibility or any trick

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the standard fields that are part of **Mailing Address**. A possible solution for you is to create custom fields and use those on the page layout.

Having a separate page layout per record type is also a solution in which you can display/hide Mailing Address completely.